# Dynamic Grand-total with lists and multi-value parameters

Tags: reporting-services, report

Basically I've created a list that subtotals according to the group.

I then created a multi-value parameter that allows the user to choose which group is shown in the report.

How can I get the grand total to reflect the parameter since its currently outside of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your grand total reflect the parameter, you could place it in a one-row table (with no header/footer).  Group by the same expression as your list, then filter the table by your parameter:

```
=Fields!YourField.Value = Parameter.YourParam.Value(0)
```

Finally have your grand total field, in the table, use the expression `=CountRows()` to get the correct number.

Hope this helps!
--Dubs

Comment: Thats pretty much what I ended up doing, I was surprised they wouldn't let me filter a textbox. 

Thanks again,